# What is the difference between Definite Integral & Indefinite Integral on the basis of their connection with derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

I'm  reading Denlinger's text on Real Analysis. There is a difference mentioned between definite integrals and indefinite integrals:

> The definite integral is a fundamentally significant concept, existing
>   independently of any connection with derivatives. The 'indefinite'
>   integral $ \int f(t) dt $, on the other hand, depends upon the notion
>   of derivatives for its definition

But, I think both 'definite' integral and 'indefinite' integral have their connection with derivatives as is clear from Fundamental theorem of calculus.
May be i am not fully getting what the above text wants to convey.

Please, explain this text in detail & help me in sorting out my confusion.

Another question: Is definite integral is also called Riemann Integral?

Comment: This is a side-comment, but maybe it will help clarify your perspective.  The concept of "area under a curve" was explored already by Archimedes: that's over 1000 years before Newton and Leibniz invented calculus!  The Fundamental Theorem links definite integrals and derivatives together, but the definite integral itself can be understood without any notion of derivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definite integrals are *defined* only using the concept of Riemann sum, therefore you don't need derivatives in order to talk about them. Ah, if you want to *compute* them - this is an entirely different business! Nobody computes definite integrals using their definition, it would be too cumbersome, but using various other techniques, in particular the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (which, indeed, needs derivatives). But don't mistake *"definition"* for *"computation"*!

Indefinite integrals, on the other hand, depend essentially on the concept of "derivative": $F$ is an indefinite integral of $f$ (denoted $F (x) = \int f(x) \ \Bbb d x$) if and only if $F' = f$.

Yes, if the interval on which you integrate is bounded and the function is bounded too, then "definite integral" is the same thing as "Riemann integral". If either the interval or the function is unbounded, you deal with an "improper integral" (which is not a Riemann integral, but is defined using a limit of Riemann integrals - but this is a different story).

Comment: means definite integral and riemann integral are different notions in general?

Comment: @PKStyles: If either of the function or the interval is unbounded, we use the term "improper integral". Some people keep calling these "Riemann integrals" or "definite integrals", but this is an abuse of terminology.

Comment: :Will you please tell me the story,you mentioned in last para?you explain very well {:-->)

Comment: :OK,you want to say -Definite integrals can be classified as Riemann Integrals and Improper integrals?Am i going right?

Comment: @PKStyles: Some people adopt the point of view expressed in your latest comment; others are stricter and consider Riemann integrals to be a synonym for definite integrals. There is no consensus here, but this is also not a major issue.

Comment: :So,what is the exact difference among three of them?

Comment: M:Riemann Sum & Darboux Sum are same things?

Answer (score 1):

The definite integral  is *by definition* a limit of a certain class of sums (the class of the *Riemann sums*, by the way): no relation *a priori* with the derivatives.
The indefinite integral is *by definition* the primitive of a function, or its 'antiderivative' (hence it is related, by definition, to the concept of derivative). So the two integrals are independently defined concepts. The *Foundamental Theorem of Calculus* establishes an amazing relation between these two independent concepts (because of that it is 'foundamental'). But this is a *theorem*, not a definition of integral: it establishes a connection which goes beyond to what the definitions of definite and indefinite integrals explicitely state.

Comment: :Riemann Sum & Darboux Sum are same things?